# How do I make my code more efficient in python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm a beginner at python and this is with reference to the turtle module.

m1, m2, m3 and m4 are turtles. I'm trying to get them to move from one point to another but each at a different speed. The code is quite repetitive. Is there any way to sort of combine all of them to make the code more efficient? Also would that be a suitable method to get all turtles to start moving at the same time?

Here's the code:

```
for i in range(5):
    m1.speed(randint(0,10))
    m1.pd()
    m1.forward(30)

    m2.speed(randint(0,10))
    m2.pd()
    m2.forward(30)

    m3.speed(randint(0,10))
    m3.pd()
    m3.forward(30)

    m4.speed(randint(0,10))
    m4.pd()
    m4.forward(30)
```

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Answer (score 0):

Also iterate over the `m`s:

```
for i in range(5):
    for m in (m1, m2, m3, m4):
        m.speed(randint(0, 10))
        m.pd()
        m.forward(30)
```

Comment: Does not address "get all turtles to start moving at the same time".